# Enumerate files in directory with wildcard in C

Tags: c, file, directory, enumerate

I use code like this to enumerate all shader files in subdirectory shaders:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
shader_counter = 1;
pclog("searching shader files \n");
hFind = FindFirstFile("shaders\\*.fx", &FindFileData);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    pclog("no shader files found \n");
}
else
{
    pclog("shader files found \n");
    while(hFind!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
          pclog("Filename=%s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);
          hFind = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData);
          shader_counter++;
    }
    pclog("Exit loop\n");
    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

But it only outputs 3 files out of many and crashes. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit , this is correct code to enumerate subdirectory using wildcard , maybe someone will find it usefull:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
BOOL found = TRUE;
hFind = FindFirstFile("shaders\\*.fx", &FindFileData);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{ // directory/wildcard not found 
}
else
{
    while(found)
    {
          //printf("Filename=%s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);
          found = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData);
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger first to find where it crashes exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Microsoft documentation, the return value to [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not the same as for [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `FindNextFile` returns a boolean value:

```
    ...
    BOOL found = TRUE;
    printf("shader files found \n");
    while (found)
    {
          printf("Filename=%s\n",FindFileData.cFileName);
          found = FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData);
          shader_counter++;
    }
    printf("Exit loop\n");
    FindClose(hFind);
    ...
```

(It has to be an independent value, otherwise you would pass an invalid handle to `FindClose`.)

Comment: Thank you very much, nice catch ) I edited code with your answer.